# Any way to disable CSS scroll snap points?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, smooth-scrolling, scroll-snap-points

I have a single-page mobile bootstrap site that when scrolling, the fixed navigation bar covers over the section titles when tapping on a link in the navigation menu. I found that this is being caused by CSS scroll snap points. I tried to set `scroll-snap-type: none;` on the `.section` class for all sections but it still produces the bug. How do I properly disable CSS scroll snap points for the entire page?

Comment: Please provide example like with jsfiddle.

Comment: @Sharvan Due to the vast size of the page and possible external script interference, I cannot simply recreate the problem on a small scale. However, here's a link to the development site: https://dev.spacecoastsites.com/

Comment: links says- You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Comment: @Sharvan A U.S. VPN is required to access the site.

Answer (score 1):

May be it will help. Try below

```
 * Keyword values */
scroll-snap-type: none;
scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
scroll-snap-type: proximity;

/* Global values */
scroll-snap-type: inherit;
scroll-snap-type: initial;
scroll-snap-type: unset;
```

As same as Y follow.(scroll-snap-type-y)

```
   /* Keyword values */
scroll-snap-type-x: none;
scroll-snap-type-x: mandatory;
scroll-snap-type-x: proximity;

/* Global values */
scroll-snap-type-x: inherit;
scroll-snap-type-x: initial;
scroll-snap-type-x: unset;
```

Comment: `scroll-snap-type-x` and `scroll-snap-type-y` according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type-x and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scroll-snap-type-y are on non-standards tracks. Still, they do not fix the problem.

Comment: Without example difficult to check